# Why does insertion into a list require a pointer to a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

The textbook describes the insertion algorithm this way, my question is, can't it be accomplished by the second function, shown below which doesn't include a pointer to a pointer, instead working with *l and l.

```
void insert (list **l, int d)
{
    list *p; 

    p = malloc(sizeof(list)); 
    p.data = x;
    p.next = *l; 
    *l = p;
}


void insert1 (list *l, int d){
    list *p;
    p = malloc(sizeof(list));
    p.data = x;
    p.next = l;
    l = p; 
}
```

Comment: Because, parameter passing in C is by value.

Comment: Additionally, you might want to check if `malloc` returned NULL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything is passed by value in C. This includes your pointer. So, when you say `l = p;` at the end of your function, *this is without effect on the caller of `insert1()`*. You are just modifying a local variable of `insert1()` (that happens to hold a pointer).

However, when you say `*l = p;` at the end of `insert()`, you are writing the pointer to a memory location that's controlled by the caller. The caller typically does something similar to this:

```
list* myList = ...;
insert(&myList, ...);
```

With this, the `*l = p;` directly modifies the value of `myList` in the caller, allowing the caller to actually see an effect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Just to clarify, functions in C/C++ cannot modify a parameters value but can modify the address a pointer is referencing?

Comment: @drewyu no, they cannot, however in C++ you can use references, (`void foo(int & bar)...`)

Comment: @drewyu Functions can modify the **memory** a pointer is referencing. In the case of our double pointer argument (`list** l`), that memory happens to be the pointer variable `myList`, simply because we are passing its address with `&myList`. So, when `insert()` changes the value of `*l`, it changes the value of `myList`. Since `myList` is indeed itself a pointer, it's value is indeed an address, also. But that's rather coincidence and not relevant to the pass-by-value discussion. Just remember: If, and only if I pass a pointer, the callee may change whatever memory is behind it.

Comment: @drewyu Also, as Jabberwocky rightly notes, C and C++ behave very different in this respect. In C, `int foo = 42; bar(foo); assert(foo == 42);` is guaranteed to succeed. In C++, there is no such guarantee. And it's not the only difference between the two languages. I know it's tempting to think of C as just a subset of C++, I did so myself for a too long time. I think it's better to start thinking about C and C++ as *different* languages quickly, it may save you some nasty surprises. For instance, `list* p = malloc(sizeof(*p));` is recommended in C, but illegal in C++.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't. The problem with `insert1` is in the following line:

```
l = p;
```

This will set the value of `l` to `p`, but `l` is only a function-local variable holding the value of the pointer to the list. Changing `l` here will not have any effect outside of the function. So if I have a code like:

```
list *myList = /* ... */;
insert1(myList, 0);
```

The pointer `myList` here will not be changed. On the other hand, with the code:

```
list *myList = /* ... */;
insert(&myList, 0);
```

The pointer `myList` will be updated to point to the newly inserted value.

Answer (score 3):

*Why does insertion into a list require a pointer to a pointer ?*  it's because if you do that modification in `*l` will affect in calling function also & that's what our intention if you want to link nodes. This `*l = p;` in below code will modify the `head` node in the `calling` function probably `main()`.

`void insert (list **l, int x) {
     /*. .. */
}`

If you pass only pointer as you did in second code `*l` doesn't get modified in calling function. This `l = p;` doesn't change `head` node in calling function.